# How to add color to an error message using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my validation logic in jQuery I have this:

```
if (strippedPN.length !== 10) {
    $('#phoneNumber').after('<span color="red" id="errPhoneNumber">Phone number has to be 10 digits long.  </span>');
    proceed = false;
}
```

because I want the error message that displays next to the field, to be red. 
It doesn't work. What's wrong?

Note: I tried using `css()` before `after()` but it changes the color of the text inside the field (as expected, btw). I also tried `css()` after the `after()` and it also doesn't work. Also tried `addClass`.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div>
  <label for="phoneNumber" class="label">Phone Number</label>
  <input name="phoneNumber" type="text" id="phoneNumber" size="13">
</div>
```

Comment: Give it a class and style the class.

Comment: `color="red"` is not a valid attribute on a tag

Comment: @3dgoo, which attribute is valid, then?

Comment: You answer is below....

Comment: @Amarundo - Here is a list of valid attributes for the span tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just give it a style..

```
<style>
#errPhoneNumber {color:red; }
</style>
```

Then apply it...

```
if (strippedPN.length !== 10) {
$('#phoneNumber').after('<span id="errPhoneNumber">Phone number has to be 10 digits long.      </span>');
proceed = false;
}
```

Or if you wanna apply to multiple spans/error messages in general....a class is better.

```
<style>
 .error {color:red;}
</style>

    if (strippedPN.length !== 10) {
$('#phoneNumber').after('<span class="error" id="errPhoneNumber">Phone number has to be 10 digits long.      </span>');
proceed = false;
}
```

Comment: I tried creating a class, `.error-message` so that I don't have to do it for each error message, but assign the class to the span, but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you do it like above?? You mention using addClass, and css() earlier.....that obviously wouldn't have worked since you would be selecting #phoneNumber, not #errPhoneNumber

Answer (score 1):

You meant one of the two:

#### The deprecated font tag

`color` is an attribute of the `<font>` tag which is deprecated (=do not use it).

```
<font color="red">blah...</font>
```

#### A class attribute

```
<span class="red_text">blah...</span>
<!-- Of course you need to define styles for ".red_text" -->
```

Comment: You got it right too. I was applying the class to the wrong element. Thanks!